# Indexing to a std::vector with X,Y,Z

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<Chunk*> m_vpChunks` object, that holds a vector of chunks.
Also i have a world and X,Y,Z coordinates.

I create chunks with:

```
// Go through all chunks
    for(int x = 0; x < m_iSize; x+=CHUNK_SIZE_X)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < m_iSize; y+=CHUNK_SIZE_Y)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < m_iSize; z+=CHUNK_SIZE_Z)
            {


                // Create new chunk
                CChunk  *pChunk =   NULL;
                pChunk          =   new CChunk(CVector3(x,y,z));
                assert(pChunk);       


                // Add it to our list
                m_vpChunks.push_back(pChunk);

            }
        }
    }
```

And want to index into a chunk vector with X,Y,Z like:

```
CChunk *GetChunk(int X, int Y, int Z)
{

 return m_vpChunks[ *** ];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Define `bool operator<(const CVector3& v1, const CVector3& v2)` and store the chunks in a `std::map` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: Overload CChunk comparison (==) operator, then just loop through the `m_vpChunks` checking for a match on x, y, z

Comment: ...or use a `std::map` to store instead and use the find function

Comment: Does your vector ever change after you create it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - never, it is just created once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* it is:

```
return m_vpChunks[
  x/CHUNK_SIZE_X * (m_iSize/CHUNK_SIZE_Y * m_iSize/CHUNK_SIZE_Z) +
  y/CHUNK_SIZE_Y * (m_iSize/CHUNK_SIZE_Z) +
  z/CHUNK_SIZE_Z ];
```

---

But seriously, use a different data structure. Nested vectors come to mind, in which case you'd return:

```
return m_vpChunks[x][y][z];
```

or maybe

```
return m_vpChunks[x/CHUNK_SIZE_X][y/CHUNK_SIZE_Y][z/CHUNK_SIZE_Z];
```